# Low correlation of predictions: the "hot hand"

Tags: correlation, prediction, binary-data

In this recent article (http://www.statsblogs.com/2016/12/19/low-correlation-of-predictions-and-outcomes-is-no-evidence-against-hot-hand/
), the *Hot Hand* problem is discussed, referring to Josh Miller's lines:

> On correlations, you know, the original Gilovich, Vallone, and Tversky
>   paper found that the Cornell players’ “predictions” of their
>   teammates’ shots correlated 0.04, on average. No evidence they can see
>   the hot hand, right?
>
> Here is an easy correlation question: suppose Bob shoots with
>   probability ph=.55 when he is hot and pn=.45 when he is not hot.
>   Suppose Lisa can perfectly detect when he is hot, and when he is not.
>   If Lisa predicts based on her perfect ability to detect when Bob is
>   hot, what correlation would you expect?

I'm not an expert in statistics, but I'm quite sure that the issue, although evident in binary situations, also exists for continuous variable / covariates.

- Is that true?
- If yes, it would be hard to elaborate a code which can demonstrate that?

Comment: What, precisely, is the "issue", in the case of continuous variables?

Comment: To add to the query by @Kodiologist: It's not quite clear how you intend to generalize the concept of "prediction."  What would your "continuous variable/covariates" actually represent in this context?